# Implementation of the probability distribution computations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, probability-theory

I want to know how Mathematica’s, say `TransformedDistribution[]` works to facilitate my research on implementing and verifying it in, say Coq. Can you point me to an open source project which has this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: The author of the *tensor* open source project has implemented a lot of distributions, maybe he can help? [tensor/pdf](https://github.com/datahaki/tensor/tree/master/src/main/java/ch/alpine/tensor/pdf) (see `c` and `d`) folders.

Comment: Also found: https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/TransformedDistribution